# PHP output buffering doesn't work!

Tags: php, output-buffering

```
ob_start();

for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
  echo 'FUU';
  $output = ob_get_contents();
}

echo $output;
ob_end_flush();
```

So instead of one FUU I get 10! Why does my `ob_start()` not work?

Comment: One? Ten? Shouldn't you get twenty? You're echoing it ten times into your output buffer, then you're echoing $output, which also has it ten times, into your output buffer, then you're flushing the buffer, which which should output both sets of ten.

Comment: could be, I saw a lot of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you get what it's doing. Here's a walk through:

```
$i = 1
Output buffer = FUU
ob_get_contents()/$output = FUU

$i = 2
Output buffer = FUUFUU
ob_get_contents()/$output = FUUFUU

$i = 3
Output buffer = FUUFUUFUU
ob_get_contents()/$output = FUUFUUFUU
```

When you call `ob_get_contents` each iteration, it's getting everything that has been `echo`ed.